# Exception while loading assemblies: Could not load assemblies 'System.Drawing' - IKVM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, ikvm

I am using IKVM to convert a java library to C# that I can use in my Xamarin Project on Visual Studios. I converted all of the Jars to one dll file that I am referencing in my project. When I try to run the project this error appears:

```
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/d8c6e504/source/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 229
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   ApPOYNTments.Android
```

I know that IKVM is very out of date and depends on an earlier version of System and mscorlib ect.. I am thinking that this may be the problem, however I can't figure out how to change the versioning. System.Drawing isn't apart of Xamarin.Android so I cannot add it as a reference to the project. Any help?

Comment: Well, you will most likely need to do a reverse-engineer, convert the DLL back to a csproj and change the dependencies on `System.Drawing`

Comment: The thing is it runs on Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.IOS because they contain System.Drawing. So the libraries work but Xamarin.Android doesn't have System.Drawing @CamiloTerevinto